# Angular - create global array holding strings and images

Tags: angular, typescript

Since I'm new to Angular, this question might seem obvious to others.

I have a portfolio with several cases - I want these cases to be displayed.

Is there a way to create an *extra file* which holds the array of cases and **f.e. some images to each case** - to be able to use this array in several components by only iterating through this array?

Furthermore I'd like to display the images I've allocated to a specific case within this *extra file*, when the case (which is being displayed by `*ngFor`) is being hovered.

**How can I realize this in Angular?** - Is it even possible?

So far I've done it like this (I want this to be global and also hold images):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">

  <ul>
    <li class="text-center" *ngFor="let case of cases">
      {{ case }}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**TS:**

```
export class CaseListComponent implements OnInit {

  cases = [
    ['Diesel'],
    ['WeWork Berlin'],
    ['Fritzhansen'],
    ['Savum'],
    ['Eskay'],
    ['Diesel'],
    ['Mobilia'],
    ['Rarekind']
  ]

...

}
```

Comment: What you need is a provider/service which holds your data. Take a look at the official documentation https://angular.io/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

1. service with array and methods to handle add, remove items
2. local/sessionStorage - but storage can hold only strings, so you would have to JSON.stringify/parse, every time you write/read data